# Firebase authenticated requests to Google App Engine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

I currently have some routes in Google App Engine's app that are protected using the [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#users_api) in Google App Engine. I've now been asked to support users that do not have a Google account.

It seems to me Firebase auth is the tool I need, but I can't figure out exactly how to integrate it:

- I have made a login page, with the [drop in auth solution](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web), that redirects to one of my protected routes.
- I expected the request for that page (after the redirection) to contain a token I could check in Google App Engine.
- I know the initial auth step worked, because if I check Firebase auth on the client side on that new page, it works:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(console.log); // prints my email
```

Is there no way for the http requests to include the token so that I can check them server side?

Thanks!